# What is the proper way to georeference an image based on GCP using GDAL tools

Tags: qgis, gdal, georeferencing, ground-control

I am trying to do the Georeferencing using `CLI` provided by the `GDAL` as it is doing in the QGIS.
Tools useful are

- gdal_traslate
- gdalwrap
- gdaltransform

I have a gcps as below:

```
-gcp 3.5665368079674 172.382039707818 622077.13 3065767.9025 -gcp 245.303236050418 444.414309600493 622131.912491862 3065830.02579297 -gcp 634.581598372123 423.326092755138 622220.817025879 3065825.27750895 -gcp 303.968713236919 25.9583397712343 622145.74925 3065734.5255
```

I want the Geocoded-TIF image without GCP on it. How to achieve this with `GDAL` Tools without QGIS but as exact Output of `QGIS-Georeferencer`.

[Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzKaN.png)

Answer (score 2):

uou can use first *gdal_translate* to add GCPs to your image. I changed the pixel coordinates of GCPs to integer values (there is no much use of sub-pixel coordinates)

```
gdal_translate -gcp 4 172 622077.13 3065767.9025 \
-gcp 245 444 622131.912491862 3065830.02579297 \
-gcp 635 423 622220.817025879 3065825.27750895 \
-gcp 304 26 622145.74925 3065734.5255 RzKaN.png RzKaN_gcp.tif
```

In the second step using *gdalwarp* you can apply the GCPs for image transformation:

```
gdalwarp -r near -order 1 RzKaN_gcp.tif RzKaN_warped.tif
```

I used the nearest neighbor (*-r near*) interpolation as you image is black and white (not to blur the lines) and linear transformation (*-order 1*). Unfortunately I don't know the SRS for your GCPs, you should set target SRS with gdalwarp, too:

```
gdalwarp -r near -order 1 -t_srs EPSG:nnnn RzKaN_gcp.tif RzKaN_warped.tif
```

Substitute *nnnn* with the ESPG ID of your projection (if you know it).

Here is the result of transformation (image upside down):

[image]

Comment: I am working with `EPSG:6207`. The image should be be upside down. That is the issue what I am facing now. Is there any issue on source image? This was saved using normal photo editor. If I do this with QGIS, the image is not upside down. Just shifts the location as `GCPs`

Comment: The origin of the image (pixel) coordinates is the upper-left corner. I suppose your row coordinates are from the lower-left corner.